# Why paging3 with Mediator load APPEND Infinitely

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-paging

When I load the data to recyclerview by paging3, the data will be loaded Infinitely.....**(it means my APPEND will be execute constantly, and will constantly access my network service to load data)**

this is the key code

`Dao is used to operate the StoriesBean`

`ConstantDao is to operate the latest` **date** `that has been stored.`

```
@Dao
interface ConstantDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(bean:ConstantKey)

    @Query("DELETE FROM constant_key")
    suspend fun clear()

    @Query("DELETE FROM constant_key WHERE key = :key")
    suspend fun delete(key: String)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM constant_key WHERE key = :key")
    fun get(key:String):ConstantKey

}
```

```
@Dao
interface Dao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(passwords: List<StoriesBean>)

    @Query("DELETE FROM mydata")
    suspend fun clear()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM mydata")
    fun getAll(): PagingSource<Int, StoriesBean>
}
```

```
    private val dao: Dao = db.dao()
    private val keyDao: ConstantDao = db.constantDao()


    lateinit var date:String
    lateinit var list:List<StoriesBean>


override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, StoriesBean>
    ): MediatorResult {
        try {


            date = when (loadType) {
                LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                    Util.getTodayDate()
                }
                LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                }
                LoadType.APPEND -> {
                    val constantKey = db.withTransaction {
                        keyDao.get(KEY_MY)
                    }


                    if (constantKey.value.isEmpty()) {
                        return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                    }
                    constantKey.value
                }
            }



            list =
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    val a =service.getLatestNews().stories
                    a
                } else {

                    date = DateUtil.getPreviousString(date)


                    val b = service.getBeforeNews(date).stories


                    b

                }

            db.withTransaction {
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    dao.clear()
                    keyDao.delete(KEY_MY)
                }

                dao.insert(list)
                keyDao.insert(ConstantKey(KEY_MY, date))
            }
            return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = list.isEmpty())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            if (loadType == LoadType.APPEND)
                date = DateUtil.getNextString(date)
            return MediatorResult.Error(Throwable(message = "error"))
        }
    }
```

I have another place to use *Mediator*, but it can work.But now, I want to use Mediator again, it has this problem: my data load APPEND infinitely....

I once guess it may be the height of **Recyclerview**,but I change it from *wrap_content* to *match_parent*, it also load infinitely...

I also not add NestScrollView as Recyclerview's father viewgroup.

Comment: `RemoteMediator` will continue to load until it returns `MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)` are you sure that your API eventually does return an empty list?

As a follow-up to help me debug in case this doesn't solve your problem - could you add a `adapter.addLoadStateListener` and log the LoadStates you get?

Answer (score 0):

Verify the pageSize value when creating the PageConfig object. Maybe it's too small now.

According to the documentation:

> Should be several times the number of visible items onscreen.
> Configuring your page size depends on how your data is being loaded and used. Smaller page sizes improve memory usage, latency, and avoid GC churn. Larger pages generally improve loading throughput, to a point (avoid loading more than 2MB from SQLite at once, since it incurs extra cost).
> If you're loading data for very large, social-media style cards that take up most of a screen, and your database isn't a bottleneck, 10-20 may make sense. If you're displaying dozens of items in a tiled grid, which can present items during a scroll much more quickly, consider closer to 100.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are either sorting your data incorrectly in the UI and / or using the incorrect key for fetching the next page.  I had a similar issue where I was sorting my data by creation date, but the API I was using was not returning data based on creation date; but instead by item ID.  Although, they were generally in chronological order, it was not quite exact.  There would be a random item in the middle of the API call response that was created wayyy sooner than the rest.  This caused my remote mediator to always use the ID of an items in the center of my list for appending, instead of the item at the end.  Then when I used that ID, the next page would have the same items that were in the original refresh call.

I would suggest you take a very close look at the network responses you get back and see if the refresh call and the append call contain the same items.